# Toolbar hide on specific webview URLs not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar

I have a Toolbar with id 'toolbar_footer'. How to hide this toolbar for specific urls for eg : 'index.php' .Part of my project's mainactivity is given below I have tried many times and cant make it work properly with the given answers so updating the code with the xml layout code.

Please do help.. I am on this problemm for months

```
private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();

            urlData = url;


            if (target_url_prefix.equals(host)) {
                if(url.contains("index.php") || url.contains("login.php") || url.contains("register.php"))          {
                    System.out.println("This is my target url 2");
                    System.out.println(url);
                    //showToolBar = false;
                    findViewById(R.id.toolbar_footer).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    findViewById(R.id.toolbar_footer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (mWebviewPop != null) {
                    mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                    mWebviewPop = null;
                }

                return false;

            }

            boolean result = UrlHander.checkUrl(MainActivity.this, url);
            if (result) {
                ProgressDialogHelper.dismissProgress();
            } else {
                currentUrl = url;

                if (!show_content) {
                    if(url.contains("index.php") || url.contains("login.php") || url.contains("register.php"))          {
                        System.out.println("This is my target url 2");
                        System.out.println(url);
                        //showToolBar = false;
                        findViewById(R.id.toolbar_footer).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        findViewById(R.id.fab).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        findViewById(R.id.toolbar_footer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.fab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    ProgressDialogHelper.showProgress(MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }


        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            if (!NetworkHandler.isNetworkAvailable(view.getContext())) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/NoInternet.html");

            }
            hideStatusBar();
            ProgressDialogHelper.dismissProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            if (!NetworkHandler.isNetworkAvailable(view.getContext())) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/NoInternet.html");
            }
            hideStatusBar();
            ProgressDialogHelper.dismissProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            if (!NetworkHandler.isNetworkAvailable(view.getContext())) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/NoInternet.html");
            }
            hideStatusBar();
            ProgressDialogHelper.dismissProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if(url.contains("index.php") || url.contains("login.php") || url.contains("register.php"))          {
                System.out.println("This is my target url 2");
                System.out.println(url);
                //showToolBar = false;
                findViewById(R.id.toolbar_footer).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.fab).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                findViewById(R.id.toolbar_footer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.fab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
```

My Layout File is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/webview_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:context=".universalwebview.MainActivity">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        app:backgroundTint="#00a478"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="#00a470" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#333"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home"
            android:tint="@color/tintcolor" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            android:tint="@color/tintcolor" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/uploadvideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
            android:tint="#00a478" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_profile"
            android:tint="@color/tintcolor" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            android:tint="@color/tintcolor" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

for hiding toolbar you gotta put this line.
 `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

So first check if the url and then put this line in if block `if(url.contains(“your text”){
getSupportActionBar().hide();
}`